# Is it better to put multiple numbers in multiple int vars or in one int[] array?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, integer

Just wondering cause I often find myself giving input like coordinates (X, Y) and was wondering which case is better.
If I store 3 int in one array I have a reduction of the code to 1/3, but are there more reason to prefer array over multiple vars?

Example to clarify:

```
int[] coord = new int[2];
coord[0] = 3;
coord[1] = 2;
```

or

```
int x = 3;
int y = 2;
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? e.g. Can you provide a sample method and a sample input?

Comment: Explicit variables are more readable - your second example is much more readable than the first, for example, and the variable names convey information. Arrays and other collections are perfect when they represent an actual set of things - so an array of coordinates (as in your example) would make sense if you are operating on sets of coordinates, without any concern for which one is x, which one is y, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that if the coordinates are so tightly coupled that you always pass both of them together (which I believe to be true), you can create a struct to encapsulate them.

```
public struct Coords
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coords(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
    }
}
```

In such scenario you can pass it like this:

```
var c = new Coords(1, 2);
MyMethod(c);
```

You have an optimization tag attached to your question, but if the problem is not critical to your application's performance, I'd go with readability/design over nanoseconds.

Comment: Also, consider using an immutable `struct` instead. It may be better suited for coordinates.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the invaluable comment. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depens on what you're using the values for.

If you're holding a ton of values, like in a game, you should make it easily readable for yourself and maybe other coders and clarify what a value means.

You shouldn't hold many values in one array, like say HP, MP, speed, rotation, height, width,... and not clarifying what they are.

But you should say HP=100; MP=80, ... 
In cases like this, there's almost everytime a 'player' class though.
That class contains player.hitpoints, player.magicpoints, player.speed, ...

But for coordinates, what I think programmers use is an array with x, y (and sometime z) coordinates.